# No update popup when releasing a new build with Crashlytics Beta

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I'm using Crashlytics Beta to send new builds of my app to my tester.

However, when distributing a new build, the current users don't get the popup telling them that a new version is available. Their status on the dashboard stays at "Installed" and never get to "Launched", maybe it's linked?

I also regularly get "logged out" of the Beta webclip on the home screen, with a "Well, this is odd" error message.

Comment: This seems like a situation where we'll likely need to grab logs and more info from you to figure out what's going on. Can you send an email to support@fabric.io with the bundle IDs that's having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta polls for new updates on iOS every 2 hours. If you're doing multiple releases in a 2 hour period the pop-up won't appear for each release.